# django Select_related(): from another model has a ForginKey To the model that will execute Select_related

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model, one for Question and two for answer

tow have a forginkey to one and one have a forginkey to users

for this purpose I use a To be grouped together at the same endpoint I add the second to the first in serializer

With this solution, Django accessed the database with the number of answers in the second form and I cannot use Select_related here

**the question is, how can I reduce database hits to the second model**

### `Models.py`

```
class Consultation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to="media/files", null=True, blank=True,
                             validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf', 'jpg', 'png'])])
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-create_at']



class ConsultaionAnswer(models.Model):
    consultation = models.ForeignKey(
        Consultation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reply')
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.consultation.content[:20] + "..."
```

### `serializers.py`

```
class ConsultaionAnswerSerilaizers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ConsultaionAnswer
        fields = ('answer',)


class ConsultationSerilaizers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    username = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        source='user.username',
        read_only=True,
    )
    reply = ConsultaionAnswerSerilaizers(read_only=True, many=True)
 

    class Meta:
        model = Consultation
        fields = (
            "id",
            "user",
            "content",
            'create_at',
            'files',
            'username',
            "reply"
        )
```

### `views.py`

```
class ConsultationView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ConsultationSerilaizers

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        consultat = Consultation.objects.select_related().filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            consultat, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**django debug tool bar**
[image]

Comment: Use [`prefetch_related` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) as `select_related` won't work for many relationships

Comment: As far as I know, the only difference between them prefetch make join in python level so they good in large date fetched but both works fine in many relations

Comment: django docs says : `Chaining select_related calls works in a similar way to other methods - that is that select_related('foo', 'bar') is equivalent to select_related('foo').select_related('bar').`

Comment: There is a difference though that `select_related` doesn't work with many relationships. If you read the above linked documentation you will see this line "_This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using **select_related**_"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this absloutly true 
 thats my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```py
consultat = Consultation.objects.prefetch_related('reply').filter(user=request.user)
```

Since it is a one-to-many relation, you'll need a `prefetch_related` instead (see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)). And you also need to specify which field(s) you want to prefetch as well.

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related,

Comment: @Elabbasy00 if my answer was solved your problem, please accept my answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: The correct answer belongs to  @abdul-aziz-barkat But don't mind we're here to help each other out